# Replacing XP with Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-xp

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my single partition with XP inside a folder (from the installer); machine is an old Lenovo desktop.  I have now optimized the Ubuntu, gotten it fully set up with accounts for everyone in the family, etc.  I want to get rid of the XP and shift the partition so that it is fully available to Ubuntu (without having to start from installing Ubuntu again).

Is this possible?  And if so, how do I go about it?

Can I create a new partition on the drive, move the Ubuntu into it, remove the other partition and then expand the partition with Ubuntu?

If it isn't possible, how do I take my current Ubuntu set-up and turn that into an image to install fresh over the XP system?

Hoping someone has some clear answers!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you've installed Ubuntu using wubi, and now wish to convert it into a native installation and delete Windows XP?

---

You would be less likely to run into trouble just by wiping the drive and installing Ubuntu normally, but if your heart is set on converting a Wubi install to a native install there are instructions available here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi though I've never tried them myself.